# iMessage | Slack - Firebase Dynamic Link shorten URL is not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, imessage

The Firebase shortenURL is working as expected in every app except iMessage and Slack.

The sharing screen is stuck with Slack. `handleUniversalLink` decoding returns a **404** error with iMessage.

Please note that, copy and paste of the shortenURL is working as expected.

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shortenURL], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to include some prefix text with the shortenURL and share them together.

```
let promoText = "You have been invited to this. "
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [promoText + shortenURL.absoluteString], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I've spent so much time trying to troubleshoot this bizarre behaviour. Thank you!

Comment: @Grambo: I'm delighted to hear that. Happy coding.